# Is it possible to share a SQL Server transaction between multiple programs?

Tags: .net, sql-server, distributed-transactions

I have a case where I need the following sequence for our internal tools that have to work together to prepare a database for testing purposes.

- `program1` starts, *begins* a database transaction and exits
- `program2` starts and *joins* that same database transaction, executes a bunch of statements and exits
- `program3` also starts and *joins* that same database transaction, executes a bunch of statements and exits
- `program4` starts and decide if/when to *rollback* the transaction

The programs are .Net command-line applications.

I researched `MSDTC` / `TransctionScope` but I can't find any scenario where a program starts a transaction and then exits while leaving the transaction open for other programs to join in.

Is this doable?

---

## Edit (Possible solution):

I tested [`sp_getbindtoken` / `sp_bindsession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-bindsession-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and it would work:

`program1` would do this (in .Net code)

```
begin transaction
DECLARE @bind_token varchar(255);  
EXECUTE sp_getbindtoken @bind_token OUTPUT; 
print @bind_token
```

and return/write the `bind_token` to a file where the other programs can take the token and *join* the transaction:

```
sp_bindsession ':7:FliJ.4AShUOIOjb<6^]5---0aE=--'
//Do stuff
rollback transaction
```

But `program1` would have to stay alive during the whole process to keep the session alive while the other programs join/leave the session.

The doc for this api states:

> This feature is in maintenance mode and may be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Comment: Transactions are scoped to the connection / session and you can't share connection / session between application instances. Your best bet is to allocate the work to a single app that is then called from the other apps.

Comment: Transaction behavior you're describing would be inter-process, across different process boundaries, which is not possible I'm afraid. I wonder what would happen if you do Process.Start(...) for each command-line and wrap them inside the TransactionScope.

Comment: Maybe write a program5 which get connection, strat transaction, then do 1 2 3 4 and exits.

Comment: Can't you reference these applications in a main application serving as wrapper?

Comment: The way you describe is not entirely possible. You can get close with distributed transactions in which case each process talking part in the distributed transaction must flag for a full commit.

Comment: See update to my question for a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

SQL transactions are locked to their connection. A connection cannot be shared through multiple apps.

One way to achieve your goal however is to proxy the queries from all apps to a single app which actually holds the connection and therefore its transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction are specific to each session of a connected source.  Each time a different bit of code is run independently of another, it will start a new transaction.  To have the software use the same connection, it will all have to be run from one source, in one go.  Such as one application initiating the opening connection to the database source, then running all the code needed, then terminating the code.

Unfortunately, one session cannot join another with the same transaction.